# How to disable browser prompt to confirm page refresh in an ASPX page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have an aspx page that is shown inside a windows application's (inside a WebBrowser control). 
Under a certain condition, the windows application issues a reload on the WebBrowser and this results in the following prompt to be shown:

[image]

Now this page only shows a report and this prompt is completely out of place and is actually an irritant to the end user.
I've tried changing the aspx form method to GET instead of POST as this prompt only seems to come for a page with form data, but that breaks the functionality of the page. 
 I am at my wits end now with how to disable this prompt from being shown?

Is there an event I can capture that can help supress this message?

**EDIT:** A little more detail about the scenario:
This aspx page I am working with has tabs and radio buttons as server side HTML controls.
Their statuses are maintained through hidden fields embedded in the page. Once the values of the hidden fields are set and the aspnet form submitted, that's when the browser starts detecting any refresh as a resubmission and shows the dialogue. I have gotten past the issue, details in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how we solved the issue:

As explained in my edit to the question, the change in values of the hidden fields and a subsequent form submit made the browser (rightly) flag that the page has already been submitted.
 We have now changed the form.submit() to a jQuery $.post() that looks like below:

```
$.post(myForm.action, request, function(d) {
                        // Callback function that uses the returned response data d
                        // to extract the html and render the page again after completion
                        // of the Ajax request
                    });
```

request: Is the JSON object containing the key:value pairs that maintain state of the controls

Note: In the Page_Load() method of the aspx page, one needs to set the values of the hidden fields by reading them from the HttpContext's Request object

Comment: This solution was proposed by my colleague Alok: http://stackoverflow.com/users/276878/alok

Answer (score 0):

This prompt is likely a side effect of the PRG pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) which is meant to avoid double posting of data.

You probably have a redirect on the URL you are trying to post to.

In the browser debugger (use Firebug if you can, to to get maximum details), check the network requests and look for a 301/302/303 type requests.

Comment: I have used Fiddler to examine the netwrok request and I cannot see 301/302/303 status. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "You probably have a redirect on the URL you are trying to post to"

Comment: I was suspecting you were posting to a page, which was sending a redirect to another page where the post was completed. Usually browser have protection against this by transforming the last POST to a GET. If you do not have redirect, you probably have a 'double' POST to the same page somewhere, just like if you were clicking submit twice or going back then re-submitting and the browser detects this as an 'anti-PRG pattern'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not doing a double post anywhere. Good to know about the PRG pattern!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not won to change this functionality (I think maybe change on IE on options, but not on other browsers), but you need to change your way of making the report.

Instead of make the report after a button click and a post back, try to add the parameter in the url, read this parameter and make the report.

So no post back needed to be made, and nether reload with this messages need to be done.

Comment: the reload is not a result of a button click but due to an event triggered by the application that contains the WebBrowser

Comment: @mishrsud the event triggered maybe do the post back. - maybe the problem is on the application that make this event triggers ?